# I recieved an error when I tried to generate a random letter in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a python application to practice the phonetic alphabet
this is my code

```
import time
import os
import random
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
import string
import random

def GETNEWPLATE():
    string.ascii_letters
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    char1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters
    char2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    char5 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    char6 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    char7 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    char3 = random.randomint(1,9)
    char4 = random.randomint(1,9)

plate = char1 + char2 + char3 + char4 + char5 + char6 + char7

gui = tk.Tk(className=' Number Plate Generator ')
gui.geometry("940x200")


myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size='110')


button = tk.Button(gui, text=plate, bg='Yellow', fg='Black')

button['font'] = myFont

button.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

when i run this code it gives me a popup saying invalid syntax and highlights the c in 'char2' line 13 - no shell output

I am new to python so I am not sure why this has happened and would really appreciate some help

I would also love to know if  and how I would change the font family from Helvetica to Charles Wright Bold

Comment: You seem to be missing a `)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import os
import random
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
import string
import random


string.ascii_letters
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
char1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
char2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
char5 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
char6 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
char7 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
char3 = random.randint(1,9)
char4 = random.randint(1,9)


plate = f"{char1}{char2}{char3}{char4}{char5}{char6}{char7}"

gui = tk.Tk(className=' Number Plate Generator ')
gui.geometry("940x200")


myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size='110')


button = tk.Button(gui, text=plate, bg='Yellow', fg='Black')

button['font'] = myFont

button.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

well:

1- one of the parentheses is not closed

2- you have defined a funtion, but you havent called it. what you can do is create a class and create a method for each char. but what i did was to remove the function entirely

3- randomint is not available in module random, i have used randint. i dont know what purpose you wanted form randomint but i hoped randint would help

4- line 21 from my code, you can paste strings with variables when they are stored in variable. but like this, you cant paste intigers and strings together. use the f-string to do the job instead

hope this helps

Comment: your answer was very helpful, however when I added the function and added it to the button, it doesn't work. When I click the plate, it is supposed to generate a new random one, but it instead does nothing [link](https://pastebin.com/p9xkZjFy)